# Resize image by percentage on both x and y on command line with Gimp

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, image-resizing, gimp

AFAIK, it should be possible.  I know that `convert` of ImageMagick makes this task trivial, but I cannot use ImageMagick, therefore I am leaning towards Gimp (on Windows).

I have tried with this Guile script:

```
(define (resize-image filename new-filename scale)
  (let* ((image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)))
         (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
         (width (gimp-image-width image))
         (height (gimp-image-height image)))
    (gimp-image-scale-full image (* width scale) (* height scale) INTERPOLATION-CUBIC)
    (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable new-filename new-filename)
    (gimp-image-delete image)))
```

that I run with:

```
gimp-2.8 -i -b "(resize-image \"image.jpg\" \"image-small.jpg\" 0.5)" -b "(gimp-quit 0)"
```

but I get this error:

```
(gimp-2.8:22244): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: gimp-2.8: gimp_wire_read(): error

(gimp-2.8:22244): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: gimp-2.8: gimp_wire_read(): error
batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: ( : 1) *: argument 1 must be: number
```

My solution has been inspired by this post:

http://warunapw.blogspot.it/2010/01/batch-resize-images-in-gimp.html

Comment: The problem is that you'll be funneling a small scheme/python program through command line parameters without undue interpretation of quotes or double quotes. So, Linux, OSX, or Windows?

Comment: The operating system is Windows. Anyway, could I pass a script to Gimp, to avoid quoting issues?

Comment: Technically you would not be calling a Gimp script, but a small program that runs in Gimp's environment. This program can be either self-contained, or call an existing Gimp script, or, for Python, import a module and call a function in it.

Answer (score 5):

The shortest code to scale down an image:

```
image=pdb.gimp_file_load('/tmp/bigger.png','/tmp/bigger.png')
image.scale(int(image.width*.5),int(image.height*.5))
pdb.gimp_file_save(image, image.active_layer, '/tmp/smaller.png','/tmp/smaller.png')
```

So, you can still put everything in a one liner. In Linux, that gives (brace yourself):

```
gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b 'image=pdb.gimp_file_load("/tmp/bigger.png","/tmp/bigger.png");image.scale(int(image.width*.5),int(image.height*.5));pdb.gimp_file_save(image, image.active_layer, "/tmp/smaller.png","/tmp/smaller.png")' -b 'pdb.gimp_quit(1)'
```

IIRC, due to how to the Windows shell uses quotes,  you have to use double quotes to delimit shell parameters so things are easier if you use single quotes around Python strings (untested):

```
gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "image=pdb.gimp_file_load('/tmp/bigger.png','/tmp/bigger.png');image.scale(int(image.width*.5),int(image.height*.5));pdb.gimp_file_save(image, image.active_layer, '/tmp/smaller.png','/tmp/smaller.png')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

However, there is  significant overhead when starting Gimp (especially on WIndows), so if you need to process several files, you may be better off writing code that loops over files in a directory. This gets a bit bigger and may want to keep the code in a module. From my  archives from a former life as a windows user:

Assume you have a batch.py file like this (you'll obviously have to improve the process() function, in particular pass parameters to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import os,glob,sys,time
from gimpfu import *

def process(infile):
    print "Processing file %s " % infile
    image=pdb.gimp_file_load('/tmp/bigger.png','/tmp/bigger.png');
    image.scale(int(image.width*.5),int(image.height*.5));
    pdb.gimp_file_save(image, image.active_layer, '/tmp/smaller.png','/tmp/smaller.png')
    pdb.gimp_image_delete(image)

def run(directory):
    start=time.time()
    print "Running on directory \"%s\"" % directory
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.jpg')):
            process(infile)
    end=time.time()
    print "Finished, total processing time: %.2f seconds" % (end-start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        print "Running as __main__ with args: %s" % sys.argv
```

You would call it (in Windows) as:

```
gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import batch;batch.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I haven't been able to make Python work properly on my Windows machine, therefore I have resorted to a Guile solution that does not work either (please see my updated answer).

Comment: I can't help you with script-fu. Better tell me what went wrong with Python. What version of Gimp are you using? 2.8 or stuck on 2.6?

Comment: Eventually, I used a Python library instead of Gimp. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Thats what you should have started with :)

Comment: I can't get this working on GIMP 2.10 which has introduced a new gimp-console-2.10.exe which doesn't list --batch-interpreter as a valid option. Any pointers?

Comment: @PeteDuncanson Where did I mention gimp-console? And AFAIK gimp-console takes all Gimp options. Did you get a message saying that `--bach-interpreter` was invalid?